# Data source name not found and no default driver specifie

Tags: vb.net, sqlyog

Help i am using vb.net2010 and trying to access my database through sqlyog but there seems to be an error on con.Open() line.(I'm trying to create a login form with a database and this is my first time)

```
    Public con As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
    Private Sub btnlogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
     con = New Odbc.OdbcConnection("dsn=cara")
    Dim cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
    Dim reader As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = " SELECT username,password FROM userinfo WHERE username='" & txtusername.Text & "' and password='" & txtpassword.Text & "'"

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows Then
        Admin_Page.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password")
    End If
```

Comment: sqlyog is a MySQL UI - your app cannot open the db form code using it.  You should download the MySQL [Net Provider/Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html).

Comment: it says that i already have them

Comment: Well then add a reference and use then instead of ODBC